# Simple query takes long time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a long, but simple, query that seems to take an incredibly long time to return a result (over 2 seconds).
Here is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE (`title` = 'Surprise Kanye West performance ends in fans\' disappointment'
       AND `content` = '<p>It was an only-in-New-York moment: the announcement of a surprise Kanye West performance that drew throngs of people to the streets of Manhattan in the middle of the night. But instead of a concert to remember, the night ended with a hoard of disappointed fans and allegations that police used pepper spray to disperse them.<br/>Popular: <a href=\"http://podcast.cnn.com/anderson-cooper-360/episode/all/065F3vnWEzaATm/ac360-special-2016-01-07.html\" rel=\"noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">Guns in America</a> | <a href=\"http://podcast.cnn.com/anderson-cooper-360/episode/all/09mJDnGHBvEtl7/6cgs1a.1-1.html\" rel=\"noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">Sanders Demands Clinton Apologize</a> | <a href=\"http://podcast.cnn.com/fareed-zakaria-gps/episode/all/3m0KewVpkReuAh/gfaw6g.1-1.html\" rel=\"noreferrer\" target=\"_blank\">Blindsided: How ISIS Shook The World</a><br/></p>'
       AND `poster` = '')
  OR (`title` = 'Surprise Kanye West performance ends in fans\' disappointment'
      AND `url` = 'http://www.cnn.com/2016/06/06/entertainment/kanye-west-surprise-concert-canceled/index.html'
      AND `poster` = '')
  OR `url` = 'http://www.cnn.com/2016/06/06/entertainment/kanye-west-surprise-concert-canceled/index.html' LIMIT 1;
```

Here are the columns within this table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrJiA.png

I have not set any indexes on any of the columns if that helps. What should I do to make this query run faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a compound index on `(title, content, poster)`, and another index on `url`, you should see a speedup.

**Note well**. Each `OR` clause of a query like this can only use one index. So, it won't help this query to put separate indexes on `title`, `content`, and `poster`.

**Edit**: Your `EXPLAIN` result announces that the query planner is examining almost 34K rows, one by one, to find your result set. If your query used indexes, `EXPLAIN` would tell you.

If you prefix your query with `EXPLAIN` you'll get MySQL to give you some query-planner statistics.

Read this:  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Apologies, I've edited my post to make it clear that no indexes have been applied to any of the columns.

Comment: Regarding prefixing the query with `EXPLAIN`, I've tried this but I'm not sure what I could conclude from the information given (for future use): http://i.imgur.com/TV5D0YN.png

Comment: Also, would I also put a compound index on `(title, url, poster)`?

Comment: For the query in your question, a compound index with `url` anywhere except in the leftmost position is worse than useless.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an index on `url`, and another compound one on `title, poster`. Then, since MySQL can have issues with using indexes with `OR` queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `title` = ? AND `content` = ? AND `poster` = ?
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `title` = ? AND `poster` = ?
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `url` = ? 
LIMIT 1
;
```

*Though, I have to wonder a little why you even querying by that huge content string?*